# Ninject WCF Extension ArgumentNullException using NET.TCP Binding

Tags: .net, wcf, ioc-container, ninject, ninject-extensions

I have a WCF 4 service with 2 endpoints configured to use wsHttpBinding and netTcpBinding. I am hosting the service within IIS 7.5 using WAS and am using the Ninject WCF extension to DI into my service. My service works fine when I use the wsHttpBinding endpoint to call my service but fails when I use the netTcpBinding. When I look in my Application Event Log I get the following error outlined below.

I have tried debugging the problem in VS2010 but am getting nowhere fast with this. I don’t want to have to remove Ninject from my WCF service if at all possible. I understand that I could just use wsHttpBinding but I this is an internal service and I want to get the performance gains that netTcpBindings provide.

```
WebHost failed to process a request.
 Sender Information: System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostingEnvironment+HostingManager/30180123
 Exception: System.ServiceModel.ServiceActivationException: The service '/ProfileService.svc' cannot be activated due to an exception during compilation.  The exception message is: Cannot be null
Parameter name: root. ---> System.ArgumentNullException: Cannot be null
Parameter name: root
   at Ninject.Infrastructure.Ensure.ArgumentNotNull(Object argument, String name) in c:\Projects\Ninject\ninject\src\Ninject\Infrastructure\Ensure.cs:line 20
   at Ninject.ResolutionExtensions.Get[T](IResolutionRoot root, IParameter[] parameters) in c:\Projects\Ninject\ninject\src\Ninject\Syntax\ResolutionExtensions.cs:line 37
   at System.ServiceModel.Activation.ServiceHostFactory.CreateServiceHost(String constructorString, Uri[] baseAddresses)
   at System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostingEnvironment.HostingManager.CreateService(String normalizedVirtualPath)
   at System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostingEnvironment.HostingManager.ActivateService(String normalizedVirtualPath)
   at System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostingEnvironment.HostingManager.EnsureServiceAvailable(String normalizedVirtualPath)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostingEnvironment.HostingManager.EnsureServiceAvailable(String normalizedVirtualPath)
   at System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostingEnvironment.EnsureServiceAvailableFast(String relativeVirtualPath)
 Process Name: w3wp
 Process ID: 8656
```

Is there anybody out there that may be able to help with this problem? Any help on this one would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If I'm correct, I reckon you may be using an older version which uses the `KernelContainer`. You need to set the `Kernel` on the `KernelContainer`. See:

https://github.com/ninject/ninject.extensions.wcf/blob/52bb83728774701ec42b5f76b096bec934dfe419/src/Ninject.Extensions.Wcf/KernelContainer.cs

Answer (score 4):

See the answers to the identical question in the google news group: http://groups.google.com/group/ninject/browse_thread/thread/54108ef9e848b8f0

Comment: Thanks Remo, this was my post in the Ninject group, lol. I thought I would post in both to ensure I got good coverage to what I thought may be a specialist type of question to answer. Still working on it so once I find the answer will post here for others to view.